# PHP: why my switch always picks the same value?

Tags: php, switch-statement, logical-operators

```
function getValue($v) {
        $b = 22;
        switch ($v) {
            case ($v <= $b * 1.2):
                $v1 = $b;   break;
            case ($v1 > $b * 1.2 && $v1 <= $b * 2.2):
                $v1 = $b * 2;   break;
            case ($v1 > $b * 2.2 && $v1 <= $b * 3.2):
                $v1 = $b * 3;   break;
            case ($v1 > $b * 3.2):
                $v1 = $b * 4;   break;
            default:
                $v1 = $b;
        }
        return $v1;
    }
```

the `getValue(25)` or `getValue(45)` always returns 22.

Comment: Well, then reason is most likely because you are hitting the "default" option in your switch, which most likely means that you have a error / something not being calculated correct in your switch cases.

Comment: With what $v value you have try?

Comment: You have to use `$v` in your case instead of `$v1`. There is no `$v1` in your code, so its undefined.

Comment: You're code is badly messed up. I'm pretty sure you use $v in most of the places you you $v1.

Personally, I recommend writting long understandable variable names instead of cryptic names like $v/$v1

Comment: Also Matt's answer is also valid http://stackoverflow.com/a/38301210/803358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getValue($v) {
        $b = 22;
        switch ($v) {
            case ($v <= $b * 1.2):
                $v1 = $b;   break;
            case ($v > $b * 1.2 && $v <= $b * 2.2):
                $v1 = $b * 2;   break;
            case ($v > $b * 2.2 && $v <= $b * 3.2):
                $v1 = $b * 3;   break;
            case ($v > $b * 3.2):
                $v1 = $b * 4;   break;
            default:
                $v1 = $b;
        }
        return $v1;
    }
```

Your using `$v1` instead of `$v` wrongly.

Above code will work.

Comment: This is it! Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: It's interesting that at first glance this appears to work (and indeed, it was my first solution until I read kawadhiya21's answer) because of the way PHP's type coercion works with integers and booleans. But it gives the wrong answer (`44`) for the input value `0`. You can fix this by replacing `switch ($v)` with `switch (true)` but it seems a bit clunky.

Comment: @MattRaines I dont understand why 0 outputs 44 even though the first case should evaluate to true as it does for 1. `4v <= $b * 1.2`. Can you explain that?

Comment: Because it compares the switch value `$v` (ie `0`, ie `false`) to each of the case expressions in turn. `0 <= $b * 1.2` == `true`, which is not the same as `$v`, so it evaluates `0 > $b * 1.2 && 0 < = $b * 2.2)` == `false`, which **is** the same as `$v`.

Comment: No, `getValue("0")` still returns `44`. This just isn't how a `switch` statement is supposed to work. Better to rewrite it as a series of `if` ... `elseif` ... `else`. But if you really like the syntax, you can use `switch (true)`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you could use switch like that. It needs values. It does not accept boolean conditions. Check here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 2):

You're checking the wrong variable, so you should replace `$v1` with `$v` in the `case` statements throughout. But also, `switch` statements are designed to accept constant values, so you'd be better to replace them all with `if`.

In addition, parts of your expressions are redundant because you've already checked for them. After checking that `$v <= $b * 1.2` and finding it isn't, there's no need to check that `$v > $b * 1.2` in the next expression. Your `default` clause can never be matched because **all** values of `$v` are `<= $b * 3.2` or `> $b * 3.2`.

```
function getValue($v) {
    $b = 22;
    if ($v <= $b * 1.2) {
        return $b;
    } elseif ($v <= $b * 2.2) {
        return $b * 2;
    } elseif ($v <= $b * 3.2) {
        return $b * 3;
    } else {
        return $b * 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Matt, much appreciated, I know this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

With a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), you test the given value against the cases.

So your statement does `$v == ($v <= $b * 1.2)`, `$v == ($v1 > $b * 1.2 && $v1 <= $b * 2.2)`, etc.

You can do a switch and test against `true`:

```
function getValue($v) {
    $b = 22;
    switch (true) {
        case ($v <= $b * 1.2):
            $v1 = $b;   break;
        case ($v1 > $b * 1.2 && $v1 <= $b * 2.2):
            $v1 = $b * 2;   break;
        case ($v1 > $b * 2.2 && $v1 <= $b * 3.2):
            $v1 = $b * 3;   break;
        case ($v1 > $b * 3.2):
            $v1 = $b * 4;   break;
        default:
            $v1 = $b;
    }
    return $v1;
}
```

However in this case an `if` / `else` seems like the better choice:

```
function getValue($v) {
    $b = 22;
    if ($v <= $b * 1.2) {
        $v1 = $b;
    } elseif ($v1 > $b * 1.2 && $v1 <= $b * 2.2) {
        $v1 = $b * 2;
    } elseif ($v1 > $b * 2.2 && $v1 <= $b * 3.2) {
        $v1 = $b * 3;
    } elseif ($v1 > $b * 3.2) {
        $v1 = $b * 4;
    } else {
        $v1 = $b;
    }

    return $v1;
}
```

Comment: There is a second bug (comparing `$v1` instead of `$v`).

Comment: Thanks for the input anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your case labels: they are the results of relational operations, so all of them evaluate to either true or false! `%v` will be compared to these Boolean values. That's why you're observing such similar output for your input cases.

Replace the `switch` with an `if` block and all will be well. And do review your use of `$v1`; did you mean that?

Comment: You might add the `$v1` mistake in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your switch I can see variable $v1 in the second and third and fourth case so think of the condition which we don't go through the first case so what is the variable $v1 then ? it is not set yet so it goes to the case default or first case always.